# What is the fastest way to check bits in variable using bitwise operations?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift, bitwise-and

For example I have short (2 bytes = 16 bits) variable: (in my project this is sequence of 00, 01 and 10's)

```
0001010101101001 = 0001.0101|0110.1001
```

And I want to check if this variable contains sequence of bits, for example I need '01010101' (this is 4 x 01).

What is the fastest way to check this?
I found some solutions but I am sure that exists more simple and faster solution.

```
(pseudocode)
var =  0001010101101001;
need = 0000000001010101;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
     if(var&need==need)
           return 1;
     else
           var = var >> 2;
}
```

or:

```
(pseudocode)
var =   0001010101101001;
need1 = 0000000001010101;
need2 = 0000000101010100;
need3 = 0000010101010000;
need4 = 0001010101000000;
need5 = 0101010100000000;
if(var&need1==need1) return 1;
if(var&need2==need2) return 1;
if(var&need3==need3) return 1;
if(var&need4==need4) return 1;
if(var&need5==need5) return 1;
else return 0;
```

Comment: Why not test and find out?

Comment: These two examples are mine, but I am asking if there are more easier and faster solutions

Comment: Are you sure about `var & 01010101 == 01010101`, don't you want `var & 11111111 == 01010101`?

Comment: yes, because if my var is XXXXXXXX01010101, so (var & 0000000001010101) = 0000000001010101

Comment: It's the same in that case anyway. What do you want to happen if `var = 11111111`? The code now would return 1, but should it?

Comment: As I said, var colud not be 1111111111, because it can contain only 00, 01 and 10 pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution is good:

```
for (int Count = 0; Count < 4; Count++)
{
    if ((Var & Need) == Need)
        Found = true;
    else
        Var = (UInt16)(Var >> 2);   
}
```

I actually make things complicated rather than simplifying it.

This is an alternative solution using masks.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        UInt16 Var = 0x1569;    //0001010101101001 0x1569
        UInt16 Need = 0x5A;     //0000000001011010 0x5A
                                //0000000001010101 0x55
                                //0000000001010110 0x56 
        UInt16[] Mask = { 0x00FF, 0x03FC, 0x0FF0, 0x3FC0, 0xFF00 };

        bool Found = false;
        for (int Count = 0; Count < 4; Count++)
            Found |= (((Var & Mask[Count]) ^ (Need << (Count + Count))) == 0);

        Console.WriteLine(Found);                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an other way:

```
var &= 0101010101010101
var &= var >> 2
var &= var >> 4
return var != 0
```

The odd bits are irrelevant so just removed in the first step.

Then every 4 adjacent "pieces" (of 2 bits each) are ANDed together in two steps, first every piece with the piece directly to the left of it, then compounded by doing the same thing with a distance of 2 pieces. So the result is a mask of whether a sequence of 4 "01"s starts at that position.

Finally just check if there are any bits set in that mask.